# Improper integral from 0 to infinity interval numerical methods

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the value of integral $\int_0^{\infty}(x^3-3x^2)\,e^{-4x}\,dx$. Counting it on $[0, 1]$ interval is simple using the trapezoidal or Simpson's rule.

Unfortunately I can't use those methods in this case because of the interval. I am not mathematical and I don't know all the useful methods to calculate integrals and other stuff. I am looking for the method which I can use to solve my problem.

Is there any similar method to Simpson's rule but for integrals in an infinite interval?

Comment: This integral doesn't have a finite value.

Comment: Do you know that your integral diverges?

Comment: @Paul Yes, sorry. Now its corrected.

Comment: A change of variable like $x=\frac{y-1}{y}$ sends the interval $[0,1]$ to $[0,\infty)$. This can be used to reduce improper integrals with infinite domain of integration to an improper integral with finite domain.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use numerical methods? What about exact methods? First, use the following formula:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}x^{n} e^{-ax}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{a^{n+1}}$$
And applying it to your integral,

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} (x^2-3x^3)\,e^{-4x}\,dx&= \int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-4x}\,dx - 3\int_0^{\infty} x^3 e^{-4x}\,dx \\ \\
&=\frac{2}{4^3}-3\left( \frac{6}{4^4}\right) \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{32}-\frac{18}{256} \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{32}-\frac{9}{128} \\ \\
&=-\frac{5}{128} \\ \\
&= -0.0390625
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, because its the easiest way to make code that.

Comment: @Iomanip. Why do you want to waste computer time for an approximation while there is an analytical solution easy to code ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Could you tell me what is the name of this method?

Comment: @Iomanip. As Zachary answered, you face a standard integral.